# How to get the index of a batch of elements in an array in python？

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, tuples

Hot to get the index of the region where the elements of the intercept area are located when a matrix is intercepted?
The example as follws:

```py
  array = [
    [[], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], []],
  ]
  arrayIndex = getIndex(array[:2, :2])
```

So the getIndex function should return `array[:2, :2]` each element index, the result as follws

```
  arrayIndex = [
    [[0, 0], [0, 1]],
    [[1, 0], [1, 1]]
  ]
```

Comment: Python does not have multi-dimensional arrays built-in, and in fact does not have *arrays* built-in. What you are showing in the example code is a *nested list*, and there are no constraints on the data to be rectangular. The functionality you are looking for is provided by Numpy.

Comment: Except it's also not quite clear what you're asking about. Do you want to return some of the *actual data* from the original? Or do you just want something that can *compute index values* corresponding to the slice?

Comment: The specific situation is this I'm using opencv to process the image, opencv finds the outline in the image, I need to find a rectangular region in a picture that contains the outline, and then get the coordinates of the pixels of this rectangular region, so that I can call opencv's method to determine if the point is in the outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have an Idea how to do it (If i understood you correctly).
If you want to know the indices in a master-element for all entries in a child-element you have to give both `array, array[:2, :2]` to the `getIndex` function and let it find the respective indices.

is the following what you wanted?

```
import numpy as np

def getIndex(a, a_sub):
    indices = []
    for row in a_sub:
        for entry in row:
            index = np.array(np.where( entry == a))[:,0]
            indices.append(list(index))

    return (indices)

array = np.random.random(size=(5,5))


arrayIndex = getIndex(array, array[:2, :2])
print(arrayIndex)

arrayIndex = getIndex(array, array[3:4, 1:2])
print(arrayIndex)
```

yielding

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

[[3, 1]]
```

**disclaimer**
this solution will most probably cause problems as soon as your matrix-elements are no longer unique.